# NoNode Exception for <file>

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I am trying to run an example code that uses Kafka spout for Storm. I get this error in storm worker logs:

```
015-12-08T16:48:42.633+0100 b.s.d.executor [ERROR]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/pageview/partitions
    at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:81) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.trident.ZkBrokerReader.<init>(ZkBrokerReader.java:42) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.makeBrokerReader(KafkaUtils.java:57) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:87) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3373$fn__3388.invoke(executor.clj:522) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__464.invoke(util.clj:461) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/pageview/partitions
    at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getNumPartitions(DynamicBrokersReader.java:94) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:65) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/pageview/partitions
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:111) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1590) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:214) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:203) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:199) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:191) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:38) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getNumPartitions(DynamicBrokersReader.java:91) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

This appears to suggest that the node in the zookeeper does not exist. However, if I use zkCli tool, I can see that the path exists. I am using zookeeper 3.4.6 with Kafka 0.8.2.2 and Storm 0.9.3.

Any idea what's causing this problem?

Comment: How are you creating the Kafka topic?

Comment: I am trying to run the PageView benchmark example from this benchmark set https://github.com/intel-hadoop/storm-benchmark.

Comment: The topic is supposed to be created automatically if it doesn't exist. According to my understanding atleast.

Comment: In Kafka, there's a `auto.create.topics.enable` config value (default is true) that controls whether a topic is auto created. What is yours set to?

Comment: My config files do not specify the value for this parameter so I suppose that it is set to default.